# How to replace derailleur cable housing?

Tags: repair, derailleur, cable, cable-housing

My derailleur cable housing (sheath) has exploded:

[image: Broken derailleur cable housing]

I bought a new sheath of the exact same length:

[image: cable housing]

**PROBLEM**: Now I realize that unlike brake cables that are like `[]------`, derailleur cables seem to be like `[]-------[]`.

**QUESTION**: How can I put the cable inside the housing? I don't have many tools, just screwdrivers, Allen keys and a few common others.

[image: Derailleur inside]

Answer (score 4):

The "double end" accommodates a variety of attachments. The idea is that you cut off the end that doesn't match your setup. Then the cable looks like a brake cable :-)

So, what you should do it to remove the old cable and match the end to the new cable. Then cut off the end that you don't need (cut near the "wrong" end so that you preserve the cable length). Now you'll be able to thread the cable through the housing (sheath) and make your repair.

When you remove the old cable pay attention to how the ends are attached. You'll put it back the same way.

If you don't have / can't afford the investment in a "proper" shearing type cable cutter mentioned in the comment, you will improve your chances is you cut at the very end of the cable up against the end you are removing. The metal that formed the end may help to support the cable strands and create a cleaner cut. If the end does get mangled, try to reform the end of the cable by twisting the strands back into place. Here's an example of the kind of cable cutter you're looking for (in this case a [Park Tool CN-10](http://www.parktool.com/product/professional-cable-and-housing-cutter-cn-10)).

[image: Park CN-10 Professional Cable & Housing Cutter]

Comment: And it would be worthwhile to invest in a decent scissor-type cable cutter.  The standard "diagonal" wire cutter will mangle the end of the cable.

Comment: Thanks! After I have cut the cable and inserted it inside the sheath, I guess I bought a new "attachment" and solder it to the cable? Or maybe I can reuse the existing one? It can be seen on the last picture, if you have any idea how this type of attachment is called.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: By diagonal do you mean like http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/32277640605/Free-Shipping-16mm2-Max-Cutting-Range-Germany-Type-For-Cul-Al-Only-Cable-Cutter-Electric-Scissors.jpg ? Instead, are telling me that I need something like http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1MfEnHVXXXXX9XVXXq6xXFXXXB/MPN-100-Electrical-Wire-Cable-Cutting-Plier-Flush-Scissors-Pliers-Modeling-Tool.jpg ? Thanks!

Comment: Just the other way around, the first pair you linked to look like they have blades that pass over each other and shear the cable. The curves in the blades will also help support the cable so that it holds its shape as you cut it.

Comment: Yep, you want the first style, which you'd usually have to buy in a bike shop or a bike tools site online.  The second style is the standard "diagonal" (or "dike") wire cutter sold in any hardware store.  (No idea why it got labeled "diagonal", but it's been that pretty much forever.)

Comment: I'm not sure how well the blades would hold up, but many combination wire strippers (like [these ones from Klein](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/klein-kurve/klein-kurve-wire-strippercutter-stranded-wire)) have shearing style blades – but without the notch.

Comment: What I think you are calling the "attachment' in your comment above is (surprisingly) called a "cable end" -- a tiny metal tube open at one end.  It's purpose is to keep the end of the cable from fraying.  To attach it you crimp it on, using either a pair of pliers or the crimping anvil that is well-concealed just below the swivel joint of the wire cutters in your first link.  (You do this, of course, as the last operation in your installation, after the cable is all threaded and adjusted, and cut to final length.)

Comment: @dlu - I'd be afraid that the flat blades would cause the cable end to spread.  Plus such cutters are designed for soft copper, not hard stainless steel.

Comment: I've had some luck using my vice grips to cut cables.  They have a wire cutter on the inside of the jaw.  Make sure you set the vice grips small enough that the cutting edge will fully close.  A proper cable cutter as mentioned above will most likely do a better job, but vice grips are probably the next best thing simply because they provide a ridiculous amount of leverage and the fact that they stay clamped on the cable once closed.

Comment: Cutting seems to be a tricky step that generated 8 comments already, so I created a question specifically about that, I hope it is on-topic and provides more space for exchanging ideas: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35494/how-to-cut-a-brake-derailleur-cable

Answer (score 0):

Buy the kit with cable and housing.  Cut the housing with a proper cutter and put on the ends.  Thread the cable and THEN cut the cable.  If you don't want to buy a proper cutter then pay a LBS (local bike shop).